# Converting Currency to Decimal And Converting Back To Currency Display in Email Template

Tags: apex, visualforce, email-template, formatting, currency

I have a currency field that I multiply by .5 in my apex code.

This changes the data type to a Decimal.

I want to display on a visualforce email template the newly updated number as a currency.

Should I convert it back to a Currency? When I try to do this, I get an error saying that the type is not supported.

My end goal is to display the decimal in this format: `$123,456.78`

I want the dollar sign, commas, and 2 decimal places. I feel like there must be an easier way to do this rather then sending the decimal to the VFP and then manipulating the format with a outputText. Even with this way the dollar sign does not show.

Any advice?

All Different Attempts:

```
       <p><strong>Gross Sales Run Rate:</strong>
           {!strFormattedCurrency}
       </p>

        <p><strong>Gross Sales Run Rate:</strong>
            <apex:outputText value="{0, number, #,###.##}">
            $<apex:param value="{!strFormattedCurrency}" />
            </apex:outputText>
        </p>

        <p><strong>Gross Sales Run Rate:</strong>
            <apex:outputText value="{0, number, #,###.##}">
                $<apex:param value="{!annualRevenue}" />
            </apex:outputText>
        </p>

        <p><strong>Gross Sales Run Rate:</strong>
            <apex:outputText value="${0, number, 00.00}">
                <apex:param value="{!annualRevenue}" />
            </apex:outputText>
        </p>

        <p><strong>Gross Sales Run Rate:</strong>
             <apex:outputText value="{0, number, 00.00}">
             <apex:param value="{!strFormattedCurrency}" />
             </apex:outputText>
        </p>
```

APEX:

```
public class BrokerApprovalEmailTemplate {

public Decimal annualRevenue {get;set;}
public String strFormattedCurrency {get;set;}

public void init() {
    Decimal crAnnualRevenue;
    ....
    if(creview.Half_Revenue__c == true && (creview.SIC_Code__c == '5411' || creview.SIC_Code__c == '5541')) {
       crAnnualRevenue = creview.Annual_Revenue__c * 0.50;
    }
    else if(creview.Half_Revenue__c == true){
        crAnnualRevenue = creview.Annual_Revenue__c * 0.75;
    }
    else {
        crAnnualRevenue = creview.Annual_Revenue__c;
    }
        annualRevenue = crAnnualRevenue.setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
        strFormattedCurrency = '$' + string.valueOf(annualRevenue);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just output the field?

```
<apex:outputField value="{!record.Annual_Revenue__c}" />
```

In your controller, it would be as simple as:

```
   creview.Annual_Revenue__c *= 0.50;
   ...
   creview.Annual_Revenue__c = creview.Annual_Revenue__c.setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
```

This gives you automatic currency formatting without having to deal with any extra code.